# Executing WPF Assembly from Memory

Tags: wpf, reflection, .net-assembly

This method [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/LoadExeIntoAssembly.aspx), shown below, works well for most applications.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open); // read the bytes from the application EXE file
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
byte[] bin = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
fs.Close();
br.Close();
Assembly a = Assembly.Load(bin); // load the bytes into Assembly
MethodInfo method = a.EntryPoint; // search for the Entry Point
if (method != null) 
{
     // create an instance of the Startup form Main method
     object o = a.CreateInstance(method.Name);
     // invoke the application starting point
     method.Invoke(o, null); //EXCEPTION THROWN HERE
}
```

However when I tried using it to start a WPF app, an exception was thrown:

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

The inner exception was of type System.IO.IOException:

```
Cannot locate resource 'mainwindow.xaml'.
```

Note: the application runs fine by itself normally. for the purposes of testing, an empty wpf application was compiled.

Comment: Have you renamed your usercontrol file or moved your startup location file to different location(in subfolder)?

Answer (score 0):

This error generally comes when you move your startup xaml file into different location or renamed it but forgot to update your App.xaml file. In case you renamed it just update your App.xaml file like this - `StartupUri="mainwindow.xaml"` or if you move it to different subfolder update like this - `StartupUri="FolderName/mainwindow.xaml"`

Comment: And in case you renamed it make sure the code behind file also get renamed.

Comment: that is not that problem. the application runs fine by itself normally.

Comment: Are you sure you're not starting an old version of your WPF executable "normally"?

Comment: yes i am sure. please go attempt it yourself and see the problem.. takes 2minutes to make an empty wpf app and then to make a console or whatever app to run the above code